# Javascript doesn't recognise items entered into DIV Using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

Having searched the site, I think the issue I'm having may relate to using innerHTML to populate a `<div>` but I can't quite find a solution that I can map onto my specific issue. Hope someone can help. Basically, I have an HTML page that contains a form with a text field. The page also contains an empty `<div>` which will be populated with a table-of-contents in a moment. The `<div>` is defined as:

```
<div id="toc_menu" class="menu_list">
```

I've set the onkeyup attribute of the form text field to run a Javascript function (defined in the HTML `<head>`) which defines a XMLHttpRequest and sends the value entered in the text input field (str) to a PHP page using `xmlhttp.open("GET","toc_items.php?filter="+str,true)`. The PHP page GETS the value of 'filter' and runs a MySQL query. It then produces some results which are echoed back to the empty  as a table-of-contents with main headings and subheadings using:

```
document.getElementById("toc_menu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

This works more-or-less as expected. The length of the returned table-of-contents changes as text is entered into the text field. There is, however, a problem. This table-of-contents is supposed to  have an accordion effect created using a script which is defined in the HTML `<head>`. The script was developed by Roshan Bhattarai and works beautifully when the table-of-contents list is hard-coded into the HTML page. The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    //---------------------------------+
    //  Developed by Roshan Bhattarai
    //  Visit http://roshanbh.com.np for this script and more.
    //  This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
    // --------------------------------->
    $(document).ready(function()
                      {
                      //slides the element with class "menu_body" when paragraph with class "menu_head" is clicked
                      $("#toc_menu p.menu_head").click(function()
                                                       {
                                                            $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(down.png)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
                                                            $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(left.png)"});
                                                       });
                      });
</script>
```

The table-of-contents items that are formatted as follows:

```
<p class="menu_head">HEADING</p>;
<div class="menu_body">;
   <a href="link-to-relevant-page" target="body_frame">SubHeading</a>';
</div>;
```

It appears that the table-of-contents items that are inserted into the `<div>` don't trigger the Javascript in the HTML page `<head>` (although the text is formatted correctly using CSS files also defined in `<head>`). I can manually copy the output from the PHP page and paste it into the `<div>` and the accordion effect works perfectly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the code block:

```
<p class="menu_head">HEADING</p>;
<div class="menu_body">;
<a href="link-to-relevant-page" target="body_frame">SubHeading</a>';
</div>;
```

is echoed back by PHP from the ajax call. Correct me if I'm wrong on that. If the ajax call builds this html and echos it to the screen, the above script will not work. The ajax call is made via the keyup event on the form as you stated above. However, the script above is run on 
$(document).ready. If what I'm understanding is true, the content is placed in the innerhtml of the div when the ajax call is made not when the page loads. Because there are no "p" elements with the class "menu_head" when the page loads on $(document).ready, jquery cannot bind the .click event properly. The script needs to be executed after the ajax call returns and the DOM has been updated with the new elements.

In other words on successful return from the ajax call, run the above script, not on $(document).ready. Once the elements are in the DOM, jquery can find them and bind to them the .click event. The script execution should then complete successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much. Your explanation made perfect sense. Took me a little while to work out how to implement your suggestion but now it works perfectly. I put the main part of the js script into its own function and called that function immediately after the line that inserted the new text into the div element (i.e. document.getElementById("toc_menu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;). Works like a charm! Thanks again.

Comment: Something you may want to look into in the future is the [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function in jquery. It allows several callbacks including beforeSend (which fires before .ajaxStart), error, success, and complete (which fires after either the success or error callbacks). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied your code in detail, but did notice your empty *div* element has no close tag (unless you've omitted this detail). You should always have a close tag (for *div* elements) to ensure the DOM doesn't make an invalid assumption as to where this should be inserted, use:

```
<div id="toc_menu" class="menu_list"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed off the close tag for (what I thought was) ease of understanding. But thanks for looking over the code.